# Basis vectors for square kagome (squagome) lattice

Tags: condensed-matter, crystals, lattice-model

I was wondering if someone might be able to explain how you could determine what the basis vectors would be for a decorated square lattice otherwise known as a [square kagome](https://www.google.com/search?q=square+kagome&tbm=isch) (squagome lattice)? My initial thought was that it would be [sqrt(2),sqrt(2)] but now I am not sure.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is ultimately just a square lattice, which means that a suitable choice of basis vectors is proportional to $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ in axes aligned with the lattice. The length of those vectors depends on the length scale of the lattice, which is not specified in your diagram, but it's basically the distance between equivalent points on two neighbouring P's.

The kagome pattern is what's known as a 'decoration' on the lattice, and it does not affect the lattice structure itself.